# Is the disposition of $1$s and $0$s when writing orthogonal ket vectors purely conventional?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, mathematical-physics, vectors

If I want to define the basis in the form of $4$-vectors, how do I proceed to make sure they are orthonormal with one $1$ and three $0$ in each vector? Is it just by convention?

Does it matter if I define them according to:

$$|00\rangle = (1,0,0,0)^T ;\ |01\rangle=(0,1,0,0)^T ;\ |10\rangle = (0,0,1,0)^T ;\ |11\rangle = (0,0,0,1)^T$$

or according to:

$$|00\rangle = (1,0,0,0)^T ;\ |01\rangle=(0,0,1,0)^T ;\ |10\rangle = (0,1,0,0)^T ;\ |11\rangle = (0,0,0,1)^T$$

This is to ultimately build density matrices

Comment: I does not matter, as long as you are consistent

Comment: Do you want your density matrices to look the same as the ones in the literature? If so, then you need your conventions to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter in the sense that it is purely conventional (as long of course as you are consistent in your use of the notation).

It does matter in the sense that if everyone chose their own personal convention for this, it would add unnecessary pain in reading each other's work.